# File missing after reboot

Tags: 12.04

Yesterday I installed Linux I liked how it works on my computer, everything was fine until the need to turn off the computer because when I turned off and on all my pictures, my music were missing any changes to do after you reset or unplugged again to the same....

Comment: At each restart my computer
Disappear things I see?

Comment: Are you using guest account or main account

Comment: It happened to me also while using guest account.

Comment: How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be because you are using guest account. Ubuntu's Guest account is a special type of account, which has its home directory set to the mount point of a `tmpfs` filesystem, which is used to store data which does not need to be persisted after a reboot.

The data in `tmpfs` is stored in `RAM` backed up by the `swap space`, so it is likely the data had never been written to disk in the first place, so there's basically nothing to recover.

More details on [tmpfs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)

If you're curious how guest account is set up, you can study /usr/sbin/guest-account, which is a shell script used to create/remove a guest account.

Answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/224838/190009)

Comment: Like Aatish said. the guest account, like windows and mac, will never save your pictures or music, or whatever you put on it. You can use the guest account to save the images to another Hard Drive, or a Flash drive, or a CD, or even saving it to an online storage service like Ubuntu-One or Dropbox.