# Recover data from a Guest Session

Tags: data-recovery, guest-session

I gave a job candidate a short coding test using a guest session on a Laptop with Ubuntu. When I opened the guest session I saw the message:

[image: "All data created during this guest session will be deleted when you log out"]

After the interview I closed the lid of the laptop to transport it to another room. **I did not explicitly log out.** When I opened the lid, of course, it had logged me out of my session destroying all the data. Great.

1. This is bug, right? Unless the user **expressly** logs out or switches session, it shouldn't destroy data.
2. How can I recover any data from the hard disk?

Comment: Your data did most likely not even get written to the disk at any time (at most to the swap space), as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/224826/367990). All guest files are stored in a tmpfs file system located in your RAM. I'm sorry, but you're out of luck today.

Comment: In the guest session, the automatic locking, which is enabled by default in ordinary sessions, is disabled. I can't tell if that disabling is supposed to be effective also when you close the lid. You may want to file a lightdm bug.

Comment: I created a bug report on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1575156